# insert and retrieve nested data using foreignkeys with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I am trying to see if i can use python / sqlalchemy with foreignkeys to create nested tables . Say I have two parent tables A and B that are linked to table C through interger ids as foreignkeys

Question1: What is a simple way to insert data into table C ? is it possible without first updating A and B and without fiddling with indices?

I tried:

```
#%%
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer,String,ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker,relationship
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL



import pandas as pd
from box import Box

Base = declarative_base()

class TableA(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table_a"
    a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    a_value = Column(String)


class TableB(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table_b"
    b_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    b_value = Column(String)

class TableC(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table_c"
    a_id = Column(Integer,  ForeignKey('table_a.a_id'),primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column(Integer,  ForeignKey('table_b.b_id'),primary_key=True)
    a_value = relationship('TableA')
    b_value = relationship('TableB')
    c_value = Column(String)
 

# %%
if __name__ == "__main__":

    engine = create_engine("some_url")
    # Get the metadata from the base
    metadata = Base.metadata

    # Create the table
    metadata.drop_all(engine)
    metadata.create_all(engine) 
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    newdata=TableC( a_value="AA",b_value="BB",c_value="CC")
    session.add(newdata)
```

which gives `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`

Question 2:

Say I succesd to put data into A,B,C. How can I query into TableC using a_value and b_value as conditions (rather than a_id and b_id)